# Symfony2 locale detection and translation

Tags: php, symfony, translation, locale

Here is what I'm stuck on.
I'm working on Symfony2 and trying to make the translations working. But somehow, I can't make it work as it should. Here's what I got.
In the config.yml

```
translator:      { fallback: de }
session:
        default_locale: en
```

In `messages.en.yml` I have this structure:

`Please log in: Bitte melden Sie sich an`

I also have similar files for `messages.en_US.yml`, `messages.ru.yml`, etc.

In the code I use `$this->get('session')->setLocale('ru_RU');` to change the locale.

But the translation works only when the locale is set to "en_US" or "de_DE". In any other case it returns the key, not the value. I try the translation with this code

`return new Response($this->get('translator')->trans('Please log in').'   '.$this->get('session')->getLocale());` and it returns the locale I have set.

So what can cause this problem?

Comment: Maybe a filename convention problem? Try renaming messages.ru.yml to messages.ru_RU.yml

Comment: Have tried. Didn't help. Actually I guess it translates *only* the de_DE locale. Even in case of en_US, it takes the key. Are there any settings where it might be set to translate only specific language?

Comment: hi ArVan we got an issue with 'ru' locale, non ASCII characters are not fetched correctly from .xliff; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130580/symfony2-translations-and-locale-with-not-ascii-symbols
did you experience something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself. Just needed to clean up the cache for Symfony. Used console to do so. Changed directory to `myProject/app` and used this commands to clean the cache and logs:

```
sudo rm -R cache/
sudo rm -R logs/
```

Comment: :D - this is the Symfony equivalent to MS Windows "have you tried to turn it off and on again?"

Comment: The documentation does mention you need to clear caches when adding new translation files.

Comment: Maybe it was just a matter of ```sudo``` as well, if the command ```app/console cache:clear --no-debug``` didn't worked at first. Did you try with it ?

Comment: I don't remember :) it's a too old question. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

you should clear the cache by using the symfony comand

```
app/console cache:clear --no-debug
```

then eventually restore write permission on cache/ and log/ folders as described [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup)